# How to pass object using one function?

Tags: reactjs

How can I pass the object from one component to another using only one function? I want to send key and value from "PersonalData" (nested component) and recognize them and store in userFormular (main component).

I can pass many functions to the components as a props but if I have more than 4 it does not look clean.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import PersonalData from './PersonalData'

export default function UserFormular() {
    const initialData={
        name:'Johnny',
        lastName:'Bravo',
        email:'email@email.com'
    }
    const [data,setData] = useState(initialData)   
    function updateData(){       
        <1???>
    }    
       return( 
             <PersonalData updateData={updateData} />
       )   
}
```

```
import React, {useContext, useState} from 'react'
import {MyContext} from '../utils/CustomContext'
import Header from './Header'
//MATERIAL UI 

import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';

//START
export default function PersonalData({updateData, nextPage }) {
    const [name,setName]=useState("Name")
    const [lastName,setLastName]=useState("Last name")
    const [email,setEmail]=useState("email")


    const darkMode = useContext(MyContext)
    const myStyle={
        myButtonContainer:{
            marginTop:"100px",
            display:"flex",
            flexDirection:"column",
            justifyContent:"center",
            alignItems:"center"
        },
        myButton:{
            backgroundColor:darkMode ? "#888" : "#111",            
        }
    }
 
    function handleData(e){
        updateData();
        <2???>
    }
    return (
       <>        
            <div style={myStyle.myButtonContainer}>              
                <TextField
                    helperText="Please enter your name"                    
                    label={name}
                    onChange={handleData}
                    sx={{m:6, mb:2}}
                />
                <TextField
                    helperText="Please enter your last name"                    
                    label={lastName}
                    onChange={handleData}
                    sx={{m:2}}
                />
                <TextField
                    helperText="Please enter your email"                    
                    label={email}
                    onChange={handleData}
                    sx={{m:2}}
                />
            </div>      
        </>       
    )
}
```

Thank you for the answer.
Kamil

Comment: You want to pass initialData into the child component?

Comment: What do you mean by "passing object using one function" ? It's ok to pass several functions or state objects into child components as props

Comment: "I can pass many functions to the components as a props but if I have more than 4 it does not look clean." - is a pretty subjective statement. What are you trying to pass and what is the issue other than you thinking passing more than 4 props isn't clean?

Comment: I want to enter different data in Textfields (name, lastname, email etc) in the second component and send them to the first component. Catch them and save using the useState hook.

Comment: I want to create multipage formular and store the entered data in state (in main component). If i change the pages (next, previous page) i do not lose the data. So one object with keys: name, lastname, adress etc is ok because I store in this formular only one person.

Comment: So... [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) and passing state and callbacks down?

Comment: Drew Reese - yes, but not a primitive value but whole object.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the cleanest way but i believe this is what you want.

If what you want is initialization through a function then you can use `useEffect`.

change `updateData` so it would return the state you want to share with the child.

```js
const updateData = () => data;
```

Then in child component use `useEffect` to call the `getData`, read the new state, and update the child state.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const data = updateData();
    setName(data.name);
    setLastName(data.lastName);
    setEmail(data.email);
}, [getData]);
```

This function will run on mount, or whenever the function is redefined because of state change in parent component.

You can check my [sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-knuth-1zbbw?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: aim97

I want send object from one component to another. In each formular I change different key and in main formular i need to recognize under what key I must mrite.

Comment: So you have multiple `formular` components existing side by side, and you want your `personalData` form component to select which one it's working with now, and can change its values, did i get you correctly now?.

Comment: @KamilZawiślak generally speaking, data flows in react from up to down, you can only pass data from parent to child, either through props directly or like i show in this answer (which is a function still sent by props), when multiple sibling components share a state, it's moved to the parent to hold it, when data sharing gets more mess, you tend to use `redux` for state management.

Comment: I have 4 pages and on each of them are 2-3 textfields where I enter the data of one person. In main component I want to store the data. So I need to update the data every time I change the page. At the end I want to send all data.

Comment: I really want to find the way which is clean. I do not want to pass 10 props to each component when I extend my page adding new formulars. Thank  you for your support

Comment: If you want multiple components to share a state in a clean way you can use `createContext` to create `UserContext`, put inside it all user data and whatever you want to share, then use it with `useContext` where you need it. this avoids sending `props` or using `redux`, although using  redux is preferred for "business logic" part  of the app.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion to make the code look much cleaner:
Define an interface to simplify the data

```
export interface DataInterface {
    name: string;
    lastName: string;
    email: string;
}
```

And in the PersonalData  function:

```
const [data,setData]=useState<DataInterface>();

useEffect(() => {
    const data = updateData();
    setData(data);
}, []);
```